# Browser cant access EC2 instance via public IP but can via EB domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to run my app. It's associated with a single EC2 instance (PHP 8.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.4, using Nginx) and a RDS.

The problem is that I can access the app via the EB domain (e.g. http://app21.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/) on a Browser, but I get an instant "connection refused" via the EC2 instance public IP address (e.g. 18.190.158.12). Note, its slow to load via the EB domain because its attempting to load over https (and I dont have ssl set up yet). I can also SSH into the EC2 instance.

The first thing I tried was to look at the EC2 security groups below. I added some rules to be sure https and http were both allowed via IP4 and IP6 (Screenshot ->
[EC2 Security Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLj7K.png))

In the EB configuration details it says the EB environment is not part of a VPC. That confuses me a little as I think the EC2 instance is? Anyway, navigating through the instance pages I found the ACL associated with the instance. Below are the inbound and outbound rules (Screenshots ->
[ACL Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyGXE.png),
[ACL Outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Ijm.png))

Interestingly when I ping both the EB domain and the EC2 IP they both timeout.

I'm not sure where to go next! Is it possibly a Nginx issue? It's a Laravel app but I cant imagine Laravel is causing the issue.

Let me know if there's other info I can provide! Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE-SOLVED**

Both the EB domain and the instance public IP address are now available. Its not clear to me why, but here's what I changed;

1. I changed my a-name to point to the EBS domain rather than the EC2 instance IP (I dont think should have any effect on the issue though)
2. I added a listener on the application load balancer for https (which references an AMS cert).

My domain resolves to the EB domain and the public EC2 IP address also resolves. Go figure!

Comment: FWIW http://18.190.158.32/ and http://bepo21.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ are both responding for me now. As for ping, the EB load balancer won't respond to ping and you have to add SG rules for ICMP to have an EC2 instance respond to ping.

Comment: Thanks, they are working for me too. The only thing I changed was to point my A-name to the Elastic Beanstalk domain, and add a https listener on my Application Load Balancer. Strange.